# How to make printers installed by GPO/GPP have server-side settings?

Tags: group-policy, printing, windows-server-2019, network-printer, shared-printers

I have a Windows Server 2019 domain controller which has some network printers installed using TCP/IP Port 9100 and publishes all of those printers as shares. The important thing to note is that while it's only 3 different physical printers, those 3 exist with 9 different names and settings on the server and therefore as shares. The differences are which paper bin to use and if to print portrait or not by default per printer.

All of those 9 different logical printers need to be available at the clients, therefore a GPO/GPP exists to make them available. While that works in general, the printers are available using their expected names, the server side settings corresponding for each name are NOT used. Instead, all of those printers seem to have been installed with their default settings and therefore behave differently than expected when actually used. While changing those settings per client to correspond with expected behaviour and server side name makes things work, that's obviously not the goal when having an automatism like GPO/GPP available as well.

**So, what do I need to do to get exactly the settings the share itself have?**

At least by default, so users might change those for good reasons or even disallowing the user to change the relevant settings. Though, the important thing is to at least start with a 1:1 copy of the settings the share have.

Thanks!

Comment: If you create the printer on a workstation normally, does it use the server settings?